# Dialogflow matches irrelevant phrases to existing intents

Tags: dialogflow-es

I created a chatbot which informs the user about the names of the members of my (extended) family and about where they are the living. I have created a small database with MySQL which has these data stored and I fetch them with a PHP script whenever this is appropriate depending on the interaction of the user with the chatbot.

For this reason, I have created two intents additionally to the `Default Fallback Intent` and to the `Default Welcome Intent`:

- `Names`
- `Location_context`

The first intent (`'Names'`) is trained by phrases such as 'What is the name of your uncle?' and has an output context. The second intent (`'Location_context'`) is trained by phrases such as 'Where is he living?', 'Where is he based?', 'Where is he located?' 'Which city does he live in?' etc and has an input context (from `'Names'`).

In general, this basic chatbot works well for what it is made for. However, my problem is that (after the `'Names'` intent is triggered) if you ask  something nonsensical such as 'Where is he snowing?' then the chatbot will trigger the `'Location_context'` intent and the chatbot will respond (as it is defined) that 'Your uncle is living in New York'. Also let me mention that as I have structured the chatbot so far this kind of responses are getting a score higher than `0.75` which is pretty high.

How can I make my chatbot to trigger the Default Fallback Intent in these nonsensical questions (or even in more reasonable questions such as 'Where is he eating?' which are not however exactly related with the `'Location context'` intent) and not trigger intents such as the `'Location_context'` which simply contain some similar keywords to it such as the word `'Where'`?

Comment: Updated my answer, so you can filter those false positives!

Answer (score 5):

Try playing around with `ML CLASSIFICATION THRESHOLD` in your agent settings (`Settings > ML Settings`). By default it comes with a very low score (0.2), which is a little aggressive.

> Define the threshold value for the confidence score. If the returned
>   value is less than the threshold value, then a fallback intent will be
>   triggered or, if there is no fallback intents defined, no intent will
>   be triggered.

You can see the score for your query in the JSON response:

```
{
    "source": "agent",
    "resolvedQuery": "Which city does he live at?",
    "metadata": {
        "intentId": "...",
        "intentName": "Location_context"
    },
    "fulfillment": {
        "speech": "Your uncle is living in New York",
        "messages": [{
            "type": 0,
            "speech": "Your uncle is living in New York"
        }]
    },
    "score": 0.9
}
```

Compare the scores between the right and wrong matches and you will have a good idea of which confident score is the right one for your agent.

After changing this settings, let it train, try again, and adjust it until it meets your needs.

**Update**

For queries that still will get a high score, like `Where is he cooking?`, you could add another intent, **custom fallback**, to handle those false positives, maybe with a custom entity: `NonLocationActions`, and use the `template mode` (@) in user expressions.

- where is he `@NonLocationActions:NonLocationActions`
- which city does he `@NonLocationActions:NonLocationActions`

[image]

So these queries will get 1 score in the new custom fallback, instead of getting 0.7 in the location intent.

Comment: Thanks for your response(upvote). Yes, changing the `ML THRESHOLD` is certainly a good choice. However, in not so related questions such as 'Where is he cooking?' I am getting a score of `0.81` which is pretty high and I am not sure that it is the best strategy to set the  `ML THRESHOLD` at 0.85 to solve my problem. Probably, it is a better choice to define additional entities regarding each question; for example an entity about living location so that to exclude questions about eating locations or whatever locations. What do you think?

Comment: Yeah of course, the ML Threshold won't be perfect but it's a step forward. The number depends on how many examples you got, for you it may be ok 0.85 since you may have only two intents. I would add another intent to match those false positives and handle them as fallback intent.

Comment: Pretty interesting response. I will test it and think a bit if there is any better alternative. My first impression is that even the correct questions  may unfortunately trigger this custom fallback intent...but I will test it firstly. Also I wonder what this `NonLocationActions` entity will include. In a sense it must include everything other than the words related to right questions...but then perhaps it just better to define an entity which will include words such as 'living, based, working etc' and then set a required parameter of this entity in my existing `Location_context` intent...

Comment: `NonLocationActions` would include: 'cooking', 'snowing', 'driving'... and so on. Yes you could add a `LocationActions`  and add multiple location related actions, then create a new training phrase in your Location intent: `where is he @LocationActions`.  If you just create the LocationActions, you would still get a high score when asking: `where is he snowing`, because there isn't any other intent that will challenge that score.

Comment: (Sorry I did not any perform any extensive test yet as I am working on other aspects of this agent). In this sense, `NonLocationActions` must include everything (!) or at least everything that makes sense to be followed after a 'Where' question and this is already a huge list of words and phrases. Therefore, I think that it is better to use `@LocationActions` in the existing intent.  My first thought is that the score of irrelevant phrases (e.g. 'Where is he snowing?') will be considerably lower than of the relevant ones.

Comment: Perhaps, I can also handle this even better if I set the parameter corresponding to `@LocationActions` as required (?).

Comment: If you mark it as required there will be cases that it would fail, such as: 'where is your uncle'

Comment: Ok, I will keep it in mind. Nevertheless, I am not sure if the question 'Where is your uncle?' is actually so relevant since hemay be anywhere at that moment (!)...the question is more about 'Where is he living, working, based etc?'....

Comment: I still think you need another intent to improve the accuracy of your main intent. `Where is he not living?` If you stick with one intent, that will probably get 0.9 score. And you will answer: New York.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168384/discussion-between-poete-maudit-and-marcos-casagrande).

Comment: Haha...that's a good one...However for me it's ok to respond 'He is living in New York' to the question 'Where is he not living?' since this is the only info that I know about where my uncle lives or does not live. On the other hand, in my view, asking 'Where is he snowing?' and responding 'He is living in New York.' is way more irrelevant. But yes in principle you are right.

Comment: I want to know what did you end up doing, I'm just intrigued!

Comment: Yes, for sure, I will let you know when I will do it. For the moment I working on a more advanced version of it regarding more complex queries (with the presupposition that the user is pretty serious and rational so she/he won't ask any irrelevant questions...haha).

Comment: Looking forward to it!

Comment: Yes, I will certainly mark it as acceptable if it is the right one. However, i told you that I have some doubts about it and I feel that the opposite solution (not defining `@NonLocationActions` entity but a `@LocationsActions` entity) is the best one so we will see... :)

Comment: Indeed, when I changed the default ML Threshold from 0.2 -> 0.8, almost all of my problems about wrong intent recognition vanished. We have ~20 intents and ~30 entitites.

Answer (score 4):

I am working on a chatbot using dialogflow and am getting similar problems.

Our test manager invented the 'Sausage Test' where she replaces certain words in the question with the word sausage and our bot fell apart!  Even with a threshold of 0.8 we still regularly hit issues where intents fire for nonsensical sentences, and with an enterprise level chatbot that is giving out product installation advice we could not afford to get it this wrong.

We found that in some cases we were getting max confidence levels (1) for clearly dodgy 'sausaged' input.

The way we have got round this issue is to back all the answers onto an API and use the confidence score in conjunction with other tests.  For example we have introduced Regular Expression tests to check for keywords in the question, together with parameter matching (making sure that key entity parameters were also being passed through in the data from DialogFlow).

More recently we have also started to include in the reply a Low Confidence sentence at the start of the reply i.e. 'I think you are asking about XYZ, but if not please rephrase your question. Here is your answer'.  We do this when all our extra tests fail and we have a threshold between 0.8 and 0.98.